# NVM - Updating NodeJS to the latest version - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, nvm

I'm new to Node and trying to set up NodeJS on a local machine running Ubuntu 18 and Apache. I have NVM and NPM installed and NodeJS 8.10.0. I need at least 10.14.1 installed but when I run npm install nodejs-latest I get:

```
No such file or directory, open 'root/package.json'
```

And some warning messages.

If I run nvm install 10.21.0:

```
Downloading and installing node v10.21.0...
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v10.21.0/node-v10.21.0-linux-x86.tar.xz...
##O=-#      #
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404
Binary download from https://nodejs.org/dist/v10.21.0/node-v10.21.0-linux-x86.tar.xz failed, trying source.
grep: /home/matt6/.nvm/.cache/bin/node-v10.21.0-linux-x86/node-v10.21.0-linux-x86.tar.xz: No such file or directory
Provided file to checksum does not exist.
Binary download failed, trying source.
```

Along with that I get large variety of these:

```
g++ -o /home/matt6/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v10.21.0/files/out/Release/obj.host/v8_libbase/deps/v8/src/base/functional.o ../deps/v8/src/base/functional.cc '-DV8_GYP_BUILD' '-DV8_TYPED_ARRAY_MAX_SIZE_IN_HEAP=0' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DV8_TARGET_ARCH_IA32' '-DV8_EMBEDDER_STRING="-node.56"'
```

If I run nvm list

```
-> iojs-v3.3.1

system

default -> iojs (-> iojs-v3.3.1)
iojs -> iojs-v3.3 (-> iojs-v3.3.1) (default)
node -> stable (-> N/A) (default)
unstable -> N/A (default)
lts/* -> lts/erbium (-> N/A)
lts/argon -> v4.9.1 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.17.1 (-> N/A)
lts/carbon -> v8.17.0 (-> N/A)
lts/dubnium -> v10.21.0 (-> N/A)
lts/erbium -> v12.18.2 (-> N/A)
```

Obviously I am not doing something right. Why can't I get another version of NodeJS installed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
Check it with nvm:

1. List node.js installatios using nvm:

   **nvm ls**
2. High chance the version you tried to install is also listed
3. Select the version to use using nvm

   **nvm use**

Answer (score 0):

```
wget http://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.49.0.tar.gz
tar -xvf curl-7.49.0.tar.gz
cd curl-7.49.0/
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.

Comment: OP wanted to (re)install **NodeJS**, but you tell them effectively to install an old version of **curl**, 7.49 (7.81 is current). How does your answer really solve OP's problem? Also, installing from sources can break existing installations and interfere with software package systems, so a good answer  should address this problem, too,

Answer (score -1):

`nodejs-latest` is not a means to install the latest version of NodeJS on your system. It's just a lib that helps you fetch metadata about the latest NodeJS version. Look [it's source](https://github.com/DavidCai1993/nodejs-latest/blob/master/index.js).

Now, about NVM. From the logs it's telling us that it's not finding the binaries at the `https://nodejs.org/dist/v10.21.0/node-v10.21.0-linux-x86.tar.xz` (indeed this URL gives a 404 page if you try to access from a browser).

What's the output of `nvm --version` on your system? My guess is that you're running an old version of NVM. Try updating NVM by running:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.3/install.sh | bash
```

And then try reinstalling NodeJS:

```
nvm install 10.21.0
```

Comment: My NVM version is 0.35.1 and when I run NVM install 10.21.0 I get a bunch of stuff on the screen that start with g++ -o /root/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v10.21.0/files/out/..... and a bunch more information and it just runs for hours.  Thought's?

Comment: Only now I noticed that NVM is trying to install the x86 (32-bit) version, which is not supported anymore for linux systems (nodejs is only releasing 32-bit builds for Windows). Are you somehow running a 32-bit Ubuntu 18?

Comment: I took a look and yes, i686 32-bit.  It is an old Dell Dimension 3000 computer I converted.

Comment: I'd recommend editing this question and posting the compilation logs (the "g++ ..." logs). Or closing it and posting a new question specifically about nodejs 32-bit compilation.

Comment: Bottom line is that is was just taking forever to install.  g++ is just the compiler.  It finished after 6 hours.  I think it is because it is a 32-bit machine as mentioned above.  So time to move on to  newer machine for development.  Thanks!